# Moving Gmail from Google Apps accounts to a single one

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps

We currently have two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com

There are Google Apps/Email accounts for each domain.

I would like to migrate the accounts from domain2 over to domain1 so that when you're signed in to account@domain1.com you can send and receive messages from both domains.

I have done this before with my personal gmail however never domain-wide with numerous accounts.

Is it even possible to map all of the addresses like this without having to sign in to each individual account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate the all data ([more info](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297)). The email portion of the migration (unless you use a third party tool) will be the only part that will be done at an admin level. The rest will need to be done on a user by user basis.

Once you've moved added the data from domain2.com > domain1.com, you need to delete the Google Apps account for domain2.com and add it as a secondary domain or domain alias for domain1.com. If you don't want uses to be logging in with user@domain2.com and only want them to send/receive as @domain2.com, an alias will likely be the best. Info on adding one of these can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295).

The final step will be setting up a send as on each account so they can also send as their @domain2.com addresses (they'll automatically receive if you add as an alias). These instructions can be found [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).

Good luck!